# Tkinter "Enter Verifier" in console requires passing input

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to interact with an API that requires a verifier to be entered. This normally appears in the console output where you enter the text, but i'd like to prompt a text box to enter the verifier from the user in Tkinter.

[image]

How do I capture this verifier request and allow user input in Tkinter?

Comment: This is not answerable without a LOT more details on this API that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import tkSimpleDialog
x=tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Tell me more, Tell me more","Did you get very far?")
```

Comment: edited based on your recommendation to reassess.  tkSimpleDialog is imported directly. Tested in python 2.7 under anaconda 4.4.0